# Gmail Add on for Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, gmail-addons

I am looking for a Gmail add-on which can show the Salesforce page in the Gmail right side panel. I tried using Apps-script but giving an error like "need permissions to fetch the URl". Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if anyone has worked on this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is not possible. You can't embed a page when using a Gmail Add-On. You probably need to go the route of creating a Gmail extension .